# Could we please choose a single format for visited/unvisited links and stick to it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, links

This has been bugging me ever since the "Better Homes and Gardens" site design was implemented: in the main listings of questions[*], questions that are new to you are bold/darker, while questions you have visited are not bold/lighter. In the sidebar listings, it's exactly the opposite: questions that are new to you are not bold/lighter, while questions you have visited are bold/darker.

Could we please choose one link formatting plan, and use it on all parts of the site? I don't really care which one we pick, as long as it stays consistent.

[*] The main section has two very different formats: if you click on the site logo, you get the number of votes, number of answers, and number of views side-by-side. If you click on Questions, you get the three numbers combined into one table cell. This also bothers me, but not as much as the schizophrenic link highlighting.

Comment: It's definitely the sidebar that's wrong (at least according to web conventions).  Visited links should be de-emphasized.  I hadn't even noticed the inconsistency until now, but the sidebar has been bugging me since long before I actually realized what the problem was.  I'm pretty sure this wasn't intentional, the styles must have gotten transposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this. the side bar unvisited links are darker, and lighter when visited. the change will be in the next deployment.